# WSO2 API Manager 2.6.0 How can Category and Group API In Publisher

Tags: wso2, store, publisher, ibm-api-management

I have 100 API.
and I want Category in folder for per API Group.
for example in store we have this:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Customizing+the+API+Store#CustomizingtheAPIStore-CategorizingandgroupingAPIs

BUT I want in **Publisher**.

Answer (score 0):

In APIM 2.6.0 "tags" are used to categorize or group the APIs only in the store portal. The same feature is not available in the publisher. But the "tags" are used to filter out APIs in the publisher portal. You can search the APIs based on tags in the publisher which will list out the APIs containing the search tag.
[image]